# Buttons vertical group, in bootstrap 4 align to bottom

Tags: css, angular, button, bootstrap-4, ng-bootstrap

I would like to align buttons group to buttom. Should be center in horizontal, group in vertical, but align to bottom. Now, I have that situation:

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-4">
        <div class="center-block">
            <div class="btn-group-vertical">
                <p>
                    <button class="btn btn-info btn-sm btn-block">
                        Button 1a
                    </button>
                </p>
                <p>
                    <button class="btn btn-info btn-sm btn-block">
                        Button 2a
                    </button>
                </p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Where css is:

```
.center-block {
  display: block;
  text-align: center;
}

row {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  justify-content: space-around;
}
```

[image]

Now, I have situation from 1st picture. I would like create css for the second one

Comment: The question is unclear. Could you please rephrase the sentences.

Comment: Added picture which good describe the question.

Comment: @Pavan - it is perfect! There is any possibily to change size of buttons? Now I have very small. When change size it is no center.

Comment: Try using bootstrap `btn-sm`, `btn-xs` and `btn-lg` classes on the button. If you are still not convinced with the size, you can take any of those classes and set the `font-size` property however you want.

Comment: @Pavan When I use that solution in boostrap card class. In card-body section. There is no working. One row is inside second row.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to set the position of the row to `relative` and make the `center-block` align to `bottom` keeping its position `absolute`

See below code snippet.

```css
.center-block {
  display: block;
  text-align: center;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
}

row {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  justify-content: space - around;
  position: relative;
}
```

```html
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-4">
    <div class="center-block">
      <div class="btn-group-vertical">
        <p>
          <button class="btn btn-info btn-sm btn-block">
                        Button 1a
          </button>
        </p>
        <p>
          <button class="btn btn-info btn-sm btn-block">
                        Button 2a
          </button>
        </p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Two ways:
1.

```
<div class="container d-flex h-100">
    <div class="row justify-content-center align-self-center">
     I'm vertically centered
    </div>
</div>
```

2.

```
<div class="container h-100">
    <div class="row align-items-center h-100">
        <div class="col-6 mx-auto">
            <div class="jumbotron">
                I'm vertically centered
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Greetings